# Android Google play : App rejected : Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. Issue: Not a core feature

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, policy, policy-violation

Our app got rejected 3 times with same reasons.

1st attempt :

rejection email : https://docs.google.com/document/d/10AV9Mq4EBjollo_-kgvsfNgJR8XzBhFxT5eXl3OL0eo/edit?usp=sharing

After doing research, we got that we were using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in our app. So we have removed and uploaded new release bundle on google play.

2nd attempt results same. App got rejected with same reason.

After reviewing more in detail we found that there are  "Sensitive permissions and APIs
" we need to modify under **App Content** in google play developer console. We modified it and this time we have uploaded new release bundle under **Internal Testing**. But within a 5 mins we got rejection email again.

We tried to contact google play support team too. It is already 3 days but still no any reply from google play support team via email. We got success to chat with them. But one of the google play support team member told me we have to wait. No any alternatives.

We are really stuck to know what specific changes we need to perform.

Here are the permissions which we have declared in our manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> <!-- // Add the following permission if your scenario involves reading the external storage: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> <!-- For devices running Android 10.0 or later, you also need to add the following permission: -->
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
```

Looking forward to get some help for this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered alternatives to Google Play, like self-publishing or publishing on another store?

Comment: @TechInquisitor unfortunately we need to upload on google play only! Thanks

Comment: What does your app do?